# My modelformset displays already validated forms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, modelform

I want to create a modelformset to record several forms at the same time to be able to answer many questions simultaneously.

This works only when time I backup eg 3 questions with 3 questions. If I return to my page or is the formset I have already saved the 3 fields pre-filled ...

I do not understand why it appears to me the forms I have already saved in my database ...

[image]

**This is what I get after save 2 fields in my database ... That shows me the two fields back then 2 again ... I'd like that simply displays two blank forms ...**

> My forms :

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reply
        fields = ('question','answer','user')
```

> my views.py :

```
def access(request, instance):
    replies = Reply.objects.all()
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    numPages = Page.objects.get(pk=instance)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(page=instance)
    length_questions = len(questions)
    ReplyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Reply, form=ReplyForm, extra=length_questions)
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponse('Successfully')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/baseVisite/')
    else:
        formset = ReplyFormSet()
    return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
     'formset': formset,
     'questions':questions,
     'logged_user':logged_user,
     'numPages' : numPages
     })
```

*Ignore the `instance` parameter*

and my template :

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }} {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      {{ formset.as_p }}
    </table>

    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

How do I do when I backup the other elements so that this does not appear to me that are in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the modelformset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) - by default the queryset used by the formset includes all elements in your database. The same docs show how to create a formset that doesn't include any existing elements by passing `.none()`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':  
    formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST, queryset=Reply.objects.none())
    if formset.is_valid():
        ...
else:
    formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.none())
```

Comment: I tried using this method but not like this ! It's work now !  hugely thank you!